# d3 tree diagram animation/transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I'm very new to d3 and am struggling with a tree map/diagram. I've created it using a hard-coded array and it works but I would really like the map to be rendered on screen one node at a time, like this one excellent one:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346

I'm pretty sure I need to be looping through my data array somehow rather than dumping all of the nodes into my svg placeholder all at once but I'm really struggling with how to do this. Or maybe a transition would do what I need? Here's what I've got so far (apologies for all the commented-out stabs-in-the-dark and general noobieness):

http://embed.plnkr.co/QEWeZpVTUTCJSIw0RKwP/preview

Comment: please link to the acutal plunk.

Comment: Sorry, have corrected the link (I think)

Comment: So I've improved it to use dynamically generated arrays for the nodes which I feel is a step in the right direction, but I still can't crack the 'nodes appearing one by one' thing: http://embed.plnkr.co/3yMdcy65ikBwh0jrM2oj/preview